# Firebase Database: no such instance field error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from the firebase database, but there is nothing. The debugger tells me that there is "No such instance field" in the databaseRefer and mFirebaseInstance variables. Can someone help me with this please?

```
  private void setUser() {

    currUserEmail = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".",",");
    DatabaseReference userData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    Query a=userData.orderByChild("email").equalTo(currUserEmail);
    a.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            curr_user = null;
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                curr_user = singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            }
            if (curr_user == null){
                String currUserEmail = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".",",");
                DatabaseReference userData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(currUserEmail);
                userData.setValue(new User (currUserEmail,FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

[image: my database]

Comment: you are replacing '.' with ',' in email, are your email ids stored in similar format in DB?

Comment: yes. they are in the same format.

Comment: Please indicate at which particular line of code that error occurs. Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: on this line:  a.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() @AlexMamo

Comment: It cannot be. The `a` field is correctly instantiated. Please add a screenshot if your code to see it more clearly.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/40U0Wwv @AlexMamo

Comment: what is the value of currUserEmail when you break on it ?

Comment: my email with "," instad od "."

Comment: I understand now but how is your `currUserEmail` defined? What is the value of this variable in your reference?